# I need to link table dbo.RMY_LEAD_TIME and get .StockingLevel and .LeadTime_Days for the var Items

Tags: sql-server

```
SET ANSI_NULLS OFF
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER OFF
GO

CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[udf_BuildPartNumber]
     (@storeNo varchar(5), @shipDate datetime, @carNo varchar(50))
RETURNS varchar(2000) 
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @items varchar(2000)

    SELECT 
        @items = ISNULL(@items + '^','') + im.ITEM_NUMBER
    FROM 
        dbo.TRANSFERS t
    LEFT OUTER JOIN 
        MatDump.dbo.ITM_MSTR im ON SUBSTRING(t.cic, 1,9) + '0' =  im.CIC  
    INNER JOIN 
        dbo.TRANSFER_CARS tc ON t.TRANSFER_ID = tc.TRANSFER_ID
    WHERE 
        t.date_shipped = @shipDate 
        AND t.TO_STORE_ID = @storeNo 
        AND tc.CAR_NUM = @carNo
    ORDER BY 
        t.SEQ_OR_ID_NUM 

    RETURN @items END
```

I think I need a nested select to capture the info on `RMY_LEAD_TIME`. This function will either grab `LeadTime_Days` or `StockingLevel`.

I can duplicate the function for which ever this skips. I wrote this to get the `ITEM_NUMBER` and now want to modify this to get the corresponding info from the other table. The `ITEM_NUMBER` matches the `Material_Number` on the other table.

Comment: What is the question here? It seems you have a function and you want to change it for some reason but as posted it is not at all clear what you are trying to do here.

Comment: This function returns ITEM_NUMBER, I need to use ITEM_NUMBER to CrossRef Material_Number on a table that has not been used yet.  When I try to write the new select, I get an error

Comment: Well...I have no idea what you are table structure is like, I don't even know what table you are trying to use, I have no idea what the error message you are getting is. As it sits right now your question is like taking you car to the repair shop and saying you want it modified but not providing any details about what you want. Unless you can provide some details there is nothing we can do to help.

Comment: Table1) RMY_LEAD_TIME has Material_Number, StockingLevel.  Table2) Transfers has CIC (ref number), SEQ_OR_ID_NUM, TO_STORE_ID, Date_Shipped, TransferID,  Table3) Transfer_Car has TransferID, Car_Num,  table4) ITM_MASTER has ITEM_NUMBER,   The function works correctly as far as giving me the corresponding  part number for each item inside the inventory of the car.  I wanted to try to take that part number and get the RestockLevel of each item from RMY_LEAD_TIME.

Comment: By comparing the @partNum to RMY_LEAD_TIME.MaterialNumber, I could get the restockLevel for that item.

Comment: Can you post those details in your question instead of a comment? For the question at hand I don't understand what that has to do with anything. You might take a look here. http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/jeffs/archive/2008/05/13/question-needed-not-answer.aspx

Answer (score 0):

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[Udf_buildleadtime] (@storeNo  VARCHAR(5),
                                          @shipDate DATETIME,
                                          @carNo    VARCHAR(50))
returns VARCHAR(2000)
AS
  BEGIN
      DECLARE @ldTm VARCHAR(2000)
      DECLARE @partNum VARCHAR(2000)

      SELECT @ldTm = Isnull(@ldTm + '^', '') + leadtime_days
      FROM   dbo.transfers t
             LEFT OUTER JOIN matdump.dbo.itm_mstr im
                          ON Substring(t.cic, 1, 9) + '0' = im.cic
             INNER JOIN dbo.transfer_cars tc
                     ON t.transfer_id = tc.transfer_id
             LEFT JOIN dbo.rmy_lead_time rlt
                    ON rlt.material_number = im.item_number + '-' +
                                             im.condition_code
      WHERE  t.date_shipped = @shipDate
             AND t.to_store_id = @storeNo
             AND tc.car_num = @carNo
      ORDER  BY t.seq_or_id_num

      RETURN @ldTm
  END

CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[Udf_buildleadtime] (@storeNo  VARCHAR(5),
                                           @shipDate DATETIME,
                                           @carNo    VARCHAR(50))
returns VARCHAR(2000)
AS
  BEGIN
      DECLARE @ldTm VARCHAR(2000)
      DECLARE @partNum VARCHAR(2000)

      SELECT @ldTm = Isnull(@ldTm + '^', '') + leadtime_days
      FROM   dbo.transfers t
             LEFT OUTER JOIN matdump.dbo.itm_mstr im
                          ON Substring(t.cic, 1, 9) + '0' = im.cic
             INNER JOIN dbo.transfer_cars tc
                     ON t.transfer_id = tc.transfer_id
             LEFT JOIN dbo.rmy_lead_time rlt
                    ON rlt.material_number = im.item_number + '-' +
                                             im.condition_code
      WHERE  t.date_shipped = @shipDate
             AND t.to_store_id = @storeNo
             AND tc.car_num = @carNo
      ORDER  BY t.seq_or_id_num

      RETURN @ldTm
  END

SELECT CASE tc.istruck
         WHEN 0 THEN tc.car_num
         ELSE tc.car_num + ' (Truck)'
       END
       AS CarNo,
       t.to_store_id
       AS ToStore,
       dbo.Udf_builditemlistbystore(t.to_store_id, t.date_shipped, tc.car_num)
       AS
       Contents,
       (SELECT Isnull(Substring(e.first_name, 1, 1), '')
               + ' '
               + Isnull(Substring(e.middle_name, 1, 1), '')
               + ' ' + e.last_name
        FROM   prodgang.dbo.stores s
               LEFT OUTER JOIN chris.dbo.employee e
                            ON s.jobcode = e.jobcode
        WHERE  s.storeno = t.to_store_id
               AND s.division <> 25)
       AS Consignee,
       (SELECT s.location
        FROM   prodgang.dbo.stores s
        WHERE  s.storeno = t.to_store_id
               AND s.division <> 25)
       AS Destination,
       dbo.Udf_buildstockinglevel(t.to_store_id, t.date_shipped, tc.car_num)
       AS
       StockingLevel,
       dbo.Udf_buildleadtime(t.to_store_id, t.date_shipped, tc.car_num)
       AS LeadTime
FROM   dbo.transfers t
       LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.transfer_cars tc
                    ON t.transfer_id = tc.transfer_id
WHERE  t.date_shipped = @shipDate
       AND t.qty_shipped <> 0
ORDER  BY t.to_store_id,
          t.seq_or_id_num
```

I called these two functions to return the StockingLevel and LeadTime from the RMY_LEAD_TIME Table.  Sean Lange, thank you for your constructive crit.  While I was trying to refine my questions, I was able to better do the research myself and get the answers.  Thank you again.